# rpmbuild fails on mac osx with error failed to stat

Tags: macos, maven, rpmbuild

rpmbuild is hanging when running on mac (version 10.12.6). installed rpm using homebrew.  after installing rpm, rpmbuild was successful until getting the following error

```
INFO] Building war: /…web/target/project-web-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:attached-rpm (default) @ project-web ---
[WARNING] rpm version string truncated to 2.8.0
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/BUILD
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/RPMS
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/SOURCES
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/SPECS
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/SRPMS
[INFO] Creating directory /.../web/target/rpm/project/buildroot
[INFO] Copying 1 files to 
/.../web/target/rpm/project/buildroot/usr/local/whp-jboss/server/default/deploy
[INFO] Creating spec file /.../web/target/rpm/project/SPECS/project.spec
**[WARNING] /bin/sh: line 1:  7144 Bus error: 10**           rpmbuild -bb --buildroot /.../web/target/rpm/project/buildroot --define '_topdir /.../web/target/rpm/project' --target 'noarch-apple-mac os x' project.spec
```

after getting the above error, builds are hanging.
If I run mvn build with debug option (mvn -X clean install), build is hanging on this command

```
[DEBUG] About to execute '/bin/sh -c cd '/.../web/target/rpm/project/SPECS' && 'rpmbuild' '-bb' '--target' 'noarch-apple-mac os x' '--buildroot' '/.../web/target/rpm/project/buildroot' '--define' '_topdir /.../web/target/rpm/project' '--define' '_build_name_fmt %%{ARCH}/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm' '--define' '_builddir %{_topdir}/BUILD' '--define' '_rpmdir %{_topdir}/RPMS' '--define' '_sourcedir %{_topdir}/SOURCES' '--define' '_specdir %{_topdir}/SPECS' '--define' '_srcrpmdir %{_topdir}/SRPMS' 'project.spec''
```

when i manually run command

```
    /bin/sh -c cd
 '/.../web/target/rpm/project/SPECS' && 'rpmbuild' '-bb' '--target' 'noarch-apple-mac os x' '--buildroot' '/.../web/target/rpm/project/buildroot' '--define' '_topdir /.../web/target/rpm/project' '--define' '_build_name_fmt %%{ARCH}/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm' '--define' '_builddir %{_topdir}/BUILD' '--define' '_rpmdir %{_topdir}/RPMS' '--define' '_sourcedir %{_topdir}/SOURCES' '--define' '_specdir %{_topdir}/SPECS' '--define' '_srcrpmdir %{_topdir}/SRPMS' 'project.spec'
```

I get the following response 
    Building target platforms: noarch-apple-mac os x
    Building for target noarch-apple-mac os x
    error: failed to stat /.../project.spec: m

maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

---

when running rpmbuild from SPECS directory, rpmbuild hangs

RPM version 4.14.0

Comment: problem solved by cd /usr/local/lib . lsof | grep rpm . removing file with lock .   /usr/local/var/lib/rpmold.28020/.dbenv.lock

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by removing stale lock
cd /usr/local/lib
lsof | grep rpm
-- check listing for stale lock and remove
rm -f /usr/local/var/lib/rpmold.28020/.dbenv.lock